# how to restart (recover) a paused timer in a canvas animation using d3

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, canvas

I've built the following toy example (jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ubh1zxr/); please click the stop button within 10 seconds):

```
var width = 750, height = 400;
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");   
var x=Math.random()*50;
var y=Math.random()*50;

d3.select("body")
.append("button")
.html("stop")
.on("click",function(){ti.stop()});
d3.select("body")
.append("button")
.html("restart")
.on("click",function(){ti.restart()});

var ti = d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // Clear the canvas.
context.fillStyle="red";
var t=Math.min(1,elapsed/10000)
context.fillRect(x*(1-t)+width*t,y*(1-t)+height*t,10,10);
})
```

I need to restart the animation from the position where I have paused it after clicking the stop button. My code gives me an error when clicking the restart button. Anyway in another more cumbersome code the `time.restart()` command does not work, too, so I think to haven't understood how in D3 timers can be paused/restarted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timer.restart()` is not as useful as you think. From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#timer_restart):

> *timer*.**restart**(*callback*[, *delay*[, *time*]])
>   Restart a timer with the specified callback and optional delay and time. This is equivalent to stopping this timer and creating a new timer with the specified arguments, although this timer retains the original invocation priority.

So it is not going to make the work for you. It just saves you from creating a new timer and (in the case of several timers) it will keep its priority.

Also, as you can see in the function definition, the parameter `callback` is mandatory. That's why you get `TypeError: callback is not a function` in the console.

Basically, you should convert your anonymous callback function in a named one and pass it to both the constructor and the `restart` method. But, if you try to do it, you will see that restart means restart: it starts from the beginning.

So, you can't rely on `elapsed` to calculate the position of your animation, you need to count the time yourself. Set the starting time just before creating the timer using `d3.now()` minus the time that the animation has already run (i.e. 0 in the first call).

```
var totalElapsedTime = 0;
var startTime = d3.now() - totalElapsedTime;
var t = d3.timer(myCallback);
```

Then, inside the callback calculate the elapsed time:

```
var elapsedTime = d3.now() - startTime;
// This is how d3.js calculates `elapsed`.
// The actual code is more complicated but the result is the same.
```

Record the elapsed time in the `click` event handler of the `stop` button:

```
on("click",function(){
    totalElapsedTime = d3.now() - startTime; 
    ti.stop();
});
```

Update `startTime` in the `click` event handler of the `restart` button:

```
.on("click",function(){
    startTime = d3.now() - totalElapsedTime;
    ti.restart(myCallback);
});
```

And you are done.

For the record, a real pause/resume functionality [was suggested on GitHub](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/issues/14), but has been dismissed. Other developer has [forked the project](https://github.com/woodev01/d3-timer#pausableTimer) to implement it, in case you are interested.

**Note**: in the snippet below, I have slightly simplified the code and reduced the size of the canvas so it is easier to track the animation in the snippet window.

```js
var width = 300,
    height = 150;
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .html("stop")
  .on("click", function() {
    totalElapsedTime = d3.now() - startTime;
    ti.stop();
  });
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .html("restart")
  .on("click", function() {
    startTime = d3.now() - totalElapsedTime;
    ti.restart(myCallback);
  });

var startTime = d3.now();
var totalElapsedTime = 0;
var ti = d3.timer(myCallback);

function myCallback() {
  var elapsedTime = d3.now() - startTime;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  var t = Math.min(1, elapsedTime / 10000)
  context.fillRect( width * t, height * t, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your answer you wrote `ti.restart();` in place of `ti.restart(myCallback);`. Anyway, thankyou!

Comment: @tic - Good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep track of the time when you stop the timer.
And adjust in the callback the elapsed time.

```js
var width = 750, height = 400;
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d"); 
var x=Math.random()*50;
var y=Math.random()*50;

d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .html("stop")
  .on("click",function(){t.stop(); alreadyElapsed = stopAt;});
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .html("restart")
  .on("click",function(){t = createTimer();});

var t = createTimer();
var stopAt;
var alreadyElapsed = 0;

function createTimer() {
  return d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
    elapsed += alreadyElapsed;
    stopAt = elapsed;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // Clear the canvas.
    context.fillStyle="red";
    var t=Math.min(1,elapsed/10000)
    context.fillRect(x*(1-t)+width*t,y*(1-t)+height*t,10,10);
  });
}
```

```css
rect {
  fill:steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
```